# How to make method in crudRepository to find any elements using list ids?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, hibernate-envers

There is application on Spring + jpa + jpa Crud repository + hibernate-envers

So, I have a table UserRecord with any fields

```
        Table UserRecord
id   name  surname  age version

       Table UserRecord_AUD
id   name  surname  age version REV REVINFO
```

So, when I add new user it writes into UserRecord table.
If I change age, and try to write, new version of user writes into UserRecord and old version of user moves into UserRecord_AUD table with same id.

all saved entities have own records in UserRecord_AUD

My task is get all entities from UserRecord_AUD by id's list.

Example

```
===============================
    Table UserRecord
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  23 2
  22-2  Natasha   Ivanova 22 1
===============================
    Table UsersRecord_AUD
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  9  0
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  9  1
  22-2  Natasha   Ivanova 22 0
===============================
```

I have repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> 
{}
```

I need in custom method, which can find all users from table UserRecord_AUD by id -list

instead call any times

```
repository.find(id);
```

I need to call

```
repository.find(ids);
```

How to make that:

I tried to:

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, surname, age, REV as VERSION, IDCALC from USERRECORD_AUD where PR_KEY in (:ids)", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserRecord> findHistoryByIds(List<String> ids);
```

But there is exception

> Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you
> need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure
> to compile with -parameters.; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must
> not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named
> parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.

My JPA entity is

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "UserRecord")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    
    @Column(name = "age", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String age;
    
    @Version
    private int version;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of indexed parameter, use indexes

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, surname, age, REV as VERSION, IDCALC from USERRECORD_AUD where PR_KEY in (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
List<RiskMetricRecord> findHistoryByIds(List<String> ids);
```

In case of named parameter, use `@Param`

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, surname, age, REV as VERSION, IDCALC from USERRECORD_AUD where PR_KEY in :ids", nativeQuery = true)
List<RiskMetricRecord> findHistoryByIds(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

Comment: thanks, but in second way returned same entoties.
The user wrote and update 4 times, but returns same values in old fields and same version for all records..

Comment: I will try the first way.